# What is this line of Java code doing?

Tags: java, types, charat

Kindly consider this bit of Java code. It works, but I'm trying to understand what it does.

```
char str   = 'foo'
long prime = 503;
long hash  = 0;
hash = prime + str.charAt(1);
```

I'm confused because this is mathematical addition of different data types. Would I be correct if I thought the character was converted to its ASCII value for the purposes of this math operation?

Thanks!

Comment: "Would I be correct if I thought the character was converted to its ASCII value for the purposes of this math operation?" a char is a numerical data type, there is no _conversion_.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Concat an integer to a String - use String literal or primitive from performance and memory point of view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14782804/concat-an-integer-to-a-string-use-string-literal-or-primitive-from-performance)

Comment: That code won't compile. `str` has to be a String, not a `char`

Comment: Your first line `char str   = 'foo';` doesn't make sense. May be you mean `String str   = "foo";`

Comment: @DyZ It is not a duplicate of that question : there is no String concatenation here

Answer (score 6):

First, your syntax is wrong. I corrected that (see code below). Now the value of `hash` will be 614. Because `hash = prime + str.charAt(1)` means you are adding the ASCII value of the character at index 1 of str i.e. `o`. The ASCII value of `o` is `111`. So the value of `hash` is 614 after the addition.

```
String str   = "foo";
long prime = 503;
long hash  = 0;
hash = prime + str.charAt(1);
System.out.println(hash); // This line prints 614. Because value prime is 503 and the ASCII value of `o` is 111.
```

You can play with this Ideone https://ideone.com/EcbP8x and run the code to see output.

EDIT

As @Henry pointed out, the value of character is not limited to only ASCII value in Java. So the better term to use here is Unicode code point instead of ASCII value. To know more details please refer to [What's the difference between ASCII and Unicode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19212306/whats-the-difference-between-ascii-and-unicode)

Comment: strictly speaking, it is not the ASCII value but the Unicode code point of the character (as long as it is in the BMP). Both agree in the ASCII range but many more characters can be used in Java.

Comment: Actually, it's the UTF-16 code unit, one or two of which form a Unicode codepoint. Try `String foo="";`.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. According to the [Java Language Specification, §5.6.2,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2) when you apply the addition operation `+` to a `long` and `char`, a "widening primitive conversion" will be performed on the `char`, and addition will be performed with two `long` values.

Comment: A slightly different way of saying this is that `char` and `long` aren't actually different types.  They are both integers.  So just like you can add `int` and `byte` together (and byte is widened to int) and you can add an `int` and a `long` (int is widened to long) so you can add `char` to other types of integers.  (And integers can be converted to floating point, so you can add those to `char` and other ints as well.)

Comment: I will toot my own horn here and add a link to another question I answered that involves arithmetic on `char` types: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33770180/how-do-i-store-these-printed-letters-into-an-array/33770240#33770240

Answer (score 2):

> Would I be correct if I thought the character was converted to its
>   ASCII value for the purposes of this math operation?

Yes (except you need to change your first line to `String str = "foo";`. Basically `char` is an integral type which can be used in arithmetic expressions.

Javadoc says:

> **charAt**
>
> `public char charAt(int index)`
>
> Returns the char value at the
>   specified index.

JLS (Java Language Specification) says:

> **Chapter 4. Types, Values, and Variables**
>
> The numeric types are the
>   integral types `byte`, `short`, `int`, `long`, and `char`

and

> **4.2. Primitive Types and Values:**
>
> `char`, whose values are 16-bit unsigned integers representing UTF-16
>   code units (§3.1)"

and

> **4.2.1. Integral Types and Values**
>
> For char, from `'\u0000'` to `'\uffff'` inclusive, that is, from `0` to `65535`

and

> **5.6.2. Binary Numeric Promotion**
>
> When an operator applies binary numeric promotion to a pair of operands, each of which must denote a value that is convertible to a numeric type, the following rules apply, in order:
>
> ...
>
> Widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2) is applied to convert either or both operands as specified by the following rules:
>
> ...if either operand is of type long, the other is converted to long.

and

> **15.18.2. Additive Operators (+ and -) for Numeric Types**
>
> The binary + operator performs addition when applied to two operands of numeric type, producing the sum of the operands.
>
> Binary numeric promotion is performed on the operands (§5.6.2).

Comment: You're missing the very important [**4.2. Primitive Types and Values**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2): *"`char`, whose values are 16-bit unsigned integers representing **UTF-16** code units (§3.1)"*, to truly answer the question about "ASCII value".

Comment: @andreas that was implicit from 4.2.1, but ok I added it thanks